# Is this a valid conformal map for my problem?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I need to find a conformal map $$f\colon \mathbb{D} \to \{z\;|\;|z|<1,\,z\notin \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\}.$$ This is an excercise from one of my books and their solution is completely different from mine. I don't even know if mine is correct so I wanted to ask you. I uploaded a picture where you can see what I tried.

$\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk.

In my case a conformal map is biholomorphic(bijective and holomorphic with holomorphic inverse).

[image: Conformal map]

Comment: $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the open unit disk. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: There is no Möbius transformation from the unit disk to $\{z\;|\;|z|<1,\,z\notin \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\}$. Möbius transformations map disk to disks or half-planes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Otherwise it would be trivial. – But the question has been updated. As I assumed, OP is asking for a conformal mapping, not for a Möbius transformation.

Comment: The second transformation in your chain looks wrong. $(iz-i)/(z+1)$ is a Möbius transformation, and cannot map the upper half-plane to a half-strip.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Conformal maps, as far as I know, are bijective and holomorphic with a holomorphic inverse.

Comment: @Martin R: Oh, ok I somehow assumed that this could be wrong but I thought that the boundary of this stripe could act as a circle with Infinity as the boundary on the left side of the stripe.

Comment: Never mind, I skipped the alternate definition on Wikipedia  because I assumed it didn’t need to be onto, but the inverse means it needs to be onto, I guess.

Comment: This may be the solution you were given in the book, but an intuitive approach is:  1) The unit disk is conformally equivalent to the half plane, by a Mobius transformation.  2) The half plane is conformally equivalent to a quarter plane by square rooting.  3) The map which takes a half plane to a disk restricts to taking the quarter plane to a half disk. 4) The half disk is conformally equivalent to your target domain $\{z\;|\;|z|<1,\,z\notin \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\}$ by squaring.